# Cannot init Package Manage Console in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise on Windows 10.
And I have got these errors when I tried to use PM console.

The following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFDuQ.png) occurred while loading the extended type data file:

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\typesv3.ps1xml: The file was skipped because of the following validation exception: File C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\typesv3.ps1xml cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170..
Errors occurred while loading the format data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics, , C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Event.Format.ps1xml: The file was skipped because of the following validation exception: File C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Event.Format.ps1xml cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy..
Errors occurred while loading the format data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, , C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Help.format.ps1xml: The file was skipped because of the following validation exception: File C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Help.format.ps1xml cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy..
Errors occurred while loading the format data file: Microsoft.WSMan.Management, , C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\WSMan.format.ps1xml: The file was skipped because of the following validation exception: File C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\WSMan.format.ps1xml cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy..
Errors occurred while loading the format data file: 
Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics, , C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Event.Format.ps1xml: The file was skipped because of the following validation exception: File C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Event.Format.ps1xml cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy..
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, , C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Help.format.ps1xml: The file was skipped because of the following validation exception: File C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Help.format.ps1xml cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy..
Microsoft.WSMan.Management, , C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\WSMan.format.ps1xml: The file was skipped because of the following validation exception: File C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\WSMan.format.ps1xml cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy..
```

I removed `%AppData%/Local/Microsoft/Visual Studio` folder.
And reboot laptop, reopened Visual Studio but the same errors occurred.
Can you please fix this?